# next() function in beforeEach not working router.beforeEach vue js

Tags: laravel, vue.js, vue-router

I used the `router.beforeEach` but call to `next()` function is not working. The next variable is returning error. This is the function:

```
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    if (to.matched.some(record => record.meta.requiresAuth)) {
      // this route requires auth, check if logged in
      // if not, redirect to login page.

      if (!auth.loggedIn()) {
        next({
          path: '/login',
          query: { redirect: to.fullPath }
        })
      } else {
        next()
      }
    } else {
      console.log(next);
      next() // make sure to always call next()!
    }
  })
```

This is the error that is shown in log as value of next variable ...

```
ƒ (to) {
        if (to === false || isError(to)) {
          // next(false) -> abort navigation, ensure current URL
          this$1.ensureURL(true);
          abort(to);
        .....
```

Comment: On what line do you get the error? Is it next() or the next with path and query?

Comment: I get error when I log next variable value.

Comment: This is next() fuction to load the next route

Comment: that's not an error, but just the code for the `next` function of vue-router